# Problems with creating a repeating timer in Xcode Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, timer, skspritenode

I'm currently coding a repeating timer for my game to spawn a coin every second but, when I run the code just one coin spawns & then deletes itself without anymore following, this is a sample of the code I'm using, I'm sure there's a simple answer to this but I've been stuck on this for a day.

```
@objc let coin = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Coin")

var gametimer = Timer()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    gametimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(getter: coin), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


      coin.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height)
        coin.setScale(1)
        coin.zPosition = 1
         addChild(coin)


    let moveAction = SKAction.moveTo(y: 0, duration: 0.9)

    let deleteAction = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    coin.run(SKAction.sequence([moveAction,deleteAction]))
```

Comment: The timer repeats the code for the function you name in the 'selector' argument of this line:  gametimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(getter: coin), userInfo: nil, repeats: true).  Put the code that spawns coins in that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic example to illustrate my comment:

```
// Timer property
var gameTimer = Timer()

// In viewDidLoad, for example, set the timer only once
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(spawnCoins), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


// Place the code that should repeat in this function
@objc func spawnCoins(){
       print(“new coin spawned!”)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate the help

Comment: No problem @AjsCoding :)  If my post answered your question feel free to mark it as the correct answer and/or upvote.  Cheers!

Comment: I figured out my problem I wrote the code for the coin in two separate areas from each other I just didn't realize it because I haven't cleaned up my coding until now & I tried to upvote your answer but because I have less than 15 reputation it won't display for some reason but will be recorded